# debugging entitymanager while persisting complicated entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to persist a large, complicated entity with many layers of nested sub-nodes.  The data came from an xml file that was unmarshalled from xml into java.  The persist is failing due to little glitches that I need to iron out one at a time.  Also, I will need to validate the data before I attempt to persist it.

For now, I am just trying to persist it, but the persist command is only one line of code.  How do I debug this to find out where the one line of code is failing?  I can run eclipse in debug mode, but I would have to do a lot of digging through the contents of the entity if all I have is the one line of code to stop in the debugger.  **Is there a better way to debug this so I can pinpoint the precise spot that is throwing the error rather than digging through the densely nested entity structure?**  here is my code:

```
public Long saveToDatabase(SomeDocument cd){
    final EntityManager saveManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    saveManager.getTransaction().begin();
    saveManager.persist(cd);
    saveManager.getTransaction().commit();
    saveManager.close();
    //After the object is saved, we can get the generated id:
    final Long id = cd.getHjid();
    return id;
}
```

For reference, I am enclosing the current stack trace below.  It demonstrates that there is a `Boolean` entity in the data that cannot be cast as a specific application-defined data type.  The problem is that there are at least 75 locations within the `cd` entity that have the specific datatype mentioned in the error message.  **So the stack trace here is not that important.**  What I would like is a more granular view of the deep contents of the nested entity structure, without having to manually wiggle around the variables tab of the eclipse debug view.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Boolean] expected instance/subclass of [org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized.II]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at productionmain.DataFunctions.saveToDatabase(DataFunctions.java:261)
    at productionmain.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Boolean] expected instance/subclass of [org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized.II]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.determineConcreteSubclassEntityName(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3941)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
    at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: In theory, Hibernate exceptions should include all the information you need to figure out the precise cause.  In practice, I have had a lot of luck by turning on "break on exception" in Eclipse, then I just wiggle around from there.

Comment: look in the log? look at the exception (that we can't see) ?

Comment: So what is this "HyperJAXB3" object the trace refers to, and the Boolean? Seems to be tryng to persist them using Hibernate

Comment: For those interested in the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517573/hibernateexception-unable-to-resolve-entity-name-from-class-java-lang-boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There few things to look into.

1. For the boolean type in your entity, what is the corresponding data type in database table?
2. Add try catch block and see exception object. Navigate your exception object by checking actual                                                                         cause till SQLException in debug mode.

   3. I am not able to open link of stack trace. Can you please paste here.

Comment: You need to keep checking cause, or next field of exception until you get some meaningful message.