# HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Boolean] expected instance/subclass of

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have an entity that represents the `root element` of a large `xml` file that was `unmarshalled` from `xml` to `java` using `jaxb`.  I am trying to persist it using hibernate `EntityManager.persist(elementname)`, but it is throwing a `HibernateException`.  The exception message simply states that it cannot cast a `Boolean` value as a specific object type.

Here is the code that is throwing the error at the line `persist(cd)`:

```
public Long saveToDatabase(ClinicalDocument cd){
    Long id = null;
    try{
        final EntityManager saveManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        saveManager.getTransaction().begin();
        saveManager.persist(cd);
        saveManager.getTransaction().commit();
        saveManager.close();
        //After the object is saved, we can get the generated id:
        id = cd.getHjid();
    }catch(HibernateException sqle){sqle.printStackTrace();}
    return id;
}
```

I uploaded a stripped down working eclipse project that can enable you to recreate this problem in a couple minutes.  It is a zip file that you can download [from this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/WxogQ82QdNQM2JotNKeg?b=oMnEwJOwxUm6E1ciCbIQ).  To recreate the problem on your machine, just:

```
1.) unzip the folder  
2.) import the folder into eclipse as an existing project
3.) change `persistence.properties` to include a valid username, password, and database name on your machine  
4.) then right click on `Main.java` and choose `Run As..Java Application`.
```

It will then recreate the error.  You can then review the schema in the `schema.xsd` file and the stripped down xml in the `po.xml` file.

You can view the directory structure and see the locations of `persistence.properties`, `po.xml`, `schema.xsd`, and `Main.java` in the following screen shot below:

[image]

I also get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Boolean] expected instance/subclass of [org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized.II]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at productionmain.DataFunctions.saveToDatabase(DataFunctions.java:265)
    at productionmain.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve entity name from Class [java.lang.Boolean] expected instance/subclass of [org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized.II]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.determineConcreteSubclassEntityName(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3941)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791)
    at org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: This message typically means you're trying to persist an entity that is not serializable. Include your annotated object ClinicalDocumnet, that may be helpful.

Comment: It is - it only serves to make your point though.

Comment: These classes were generated from XML by the maven plug-in or its ilk. What it apparently tried to do was create a persistent entity from a property which was a java.lang.Boolean. That being said I'm not sure what I'd do except search the generated entities for Boolean properties that should have been marked @Transient or handled in some other fashion than trying to build a persistent class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63527/discussion-between-billfromhawaii-and-codemed).

Comment: Yes - I'll take a look.

Comment: No - I'm recreating the problem (and watching the game). I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a weird naming colission here. You have two properties named `id` and `setId`. Per property, JAXB generated two a getter (`getXXX`) and, if instructed "isSetter" to check if the property is set - useful for primitive types. This "isSetter" is named `isSetXXX`.

In this case your isSetter for `setId` collides with the getter for `id`.

Issetter for `setId`:

```
@Transient
public boolean isSetId() {
    return (this.id!= null);
}
```

Getter for `id`:

```
 public II getSetId() {
    return setId;
}
```

Note `isSetId` vs. `getSetId`. This probably makes Hibernate crazy because it thinks that `isSetId` is a boolean getter whereas it expects an enity getter.

Solution: rename the `setId` property in you model using `jaxb:property` in your bindings file.